# Print the indexs of an array

Tags: arrays, netbeans, indexing

As the title says, I have an array and I need to print only the index. And I have no idea what I'm doing. I've tried several things. Here's the most recent. Thanks for any help!

```
public static void evenIndex(int[] array){
    int length = array.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        while (array[i] == 0,2,4,6,8){
            System.out.print(array[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void evenIndex(int[] array){
    int length = array.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (i%2 == 0){ // make sure i is even
            System.out.print(array[i]); // the value of the array @ index i
            System.out.print(i); // the index ?
        }
    }
}
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If you need print index then in last line print i instead of array[i]

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to simply print the index, all you need to do is print out the variable 'i' when you have a match as this is your current location, or index in the array:

```
public static void evenIndex(int[] array){
    int length = array.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        while (array[i] == 0,2,4,6,8){
            //the following will print eg. index 0 = 0, index 2 = 2, 
            //is this what is required?
            System.out.print('index ' + i + '=' + array[i]);
        }

    }
}
```